# React-Native Android: Pass Object as prop for Native Android UI Component

Tags: android, react-native

I'm creating a Native UI component for my React-Native Android app in Java. There's a fairly complex object that I need to pass in order to render the component.

Is there a way to pass an Object as a prop with the @ReactProp annotation?

Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solved this using ReadableMap.

Comment: mate, can you share some tutorial? I find it's hard to find some tutorial about this topics

Comment: I also struggled to find documentation on a lot of this. Looking at the source code for some projects helped me out a lot, i.e.: https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps